Chess Puzzle Sheet - Layout
I wanted to implement this style here in LaTeX

This is from a book by Maxim Blokh, I want to make a new version of some of his puzzles. The black and white bullets indicate how hard the puzzle is. I added (in blue) the names of the players if it was from a real game. My question is if someone can help me recreate this type of layout especially with the numbers and the bullets. I struggled to do so and was only able to create bullets like this
\node[draw, circle, fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries, inner sep=2pt] at (0,0) {6};

but I cannot get them at the right position. Also I do not know how to put the numbers there and how to get 9 puzzles on a page. Nevertheless, here is how I added the boards:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{palatino}
\begin{document}
 
Exercise 1 \hspace{5cm} Exercise 3

\begin{center}
\vspace{-30pt}
    \chessboard[showmover=false, setfen=8/3p2k1/2p1p2R/p3P1PK/P2r4/8/8/8 w - - 0 1]
    \chessboard[showmover=false, setfen=8/2r5/3N1p2/3K4/8/1P1k4/8/8 w - - 0 1, inverse]
\end{center}


\vspace{0.25cm}

Exercise 2 \hspace{5cm} Exercise 4

\begin{center}
\vspace{-30pt}
    \chessboard[showmover=false, setfen=8/7p/8/2p3P1/1p2k3/1P6/2K4P/8 w - - 0 1]
    \chessboard[showmover=false, setfen=8/kp6/p2R4/2p2pp1/2P4p/8/P7/K7 w - - 0 1]
\end{center}


\vspace{0.25cm}

Exercise 5 \hspace{5cm} Exercise 6

\begin{center}
\vspace{-30pt}
    \chessboard[showmover=false, setfen=8/7p/8/2p3P1/1p2k3/1P6/2K4P/8 w - - 0 1]
    \chessboard[showmover=false, setfen=8/kp6/p2R4/2p2pp1/2P4p/8/P7/K7 w - - 0 1]
\end{center}
\end{document}

Sorry for my poor try. A similar Layout can be found here.

A place to search for... https://ctan.org/search?phrase=chess

please provide a complete minimal example we can compile rather than just a fragment of code.

will you always have 6 or do you sometimes need to group fewer?

@cfr 6 would be nice but I think that 4 are also fine. I think one can shrink the size of the chess boards with some command.

We provide a command, \typsetboard[]<>{} and an environment, chessboards.

\typesetboard[<number>]<<number>>{<stuff>}

the first number, if specified, will be typeset black-on-white in a circle;
the second number, if specified, will be typeset white-on-black in a circle;
'stuff' is intended to be a \chessboard command, though nothing enforces this.
<number> can be between 1 and 10 inclusive. A zero value will be ignored. Other integers will be ignored. Non-integers will cause errors.


For example,
      \typesetboard[1]<1>{%
        \chessboard[ setfen=8/3p2k1/2p1p2R/p3P1PK/P2r4/8/8/8 w - - 0 1]%
      }





chessboards is an environment designed to take multiple instances of \typesetboard, though this is not enforced.

chessboards can accommodate up to six \typesetboard commands. Subsequent boards will be ignored, except that a complaint will be printed on the console/in the log.


For example,

    \begin{chessboards}
      \typesetboard[1]<1>{%
        \chessboard[setfen=8/3p2k1/2p1p2R/p3P1PK/P2r4/8/8/8 w - - 0 1]%
      }%
      \typesetboard[2]{%
        \chessboard[setfen=8/2r5/3N1p2/3K4/8/1P1k4/8/8 w - - 0 1, inverse]%
      }%
      \typesetboard[5]{%
        \chessboard[setfen=8/7p/8/2p3P1/1p2k3/1P6/2K4P/8 w - - 0 1]%
      }%
      \typesetboard[2]<2>{%
        \chessboard[setfen=8/kp6/p2R4/2p2pp1/2P4p/8/P7/K7 w - - 0 1]%
      }%
      \typesetboard<3>{%
        \chessboard[setfen=8/7p/8/2p3P1/1p2k3/1P6/2K4P/8 w - - 0 1]%
      }%
      \typesetboard[5]{%
        \chessboard[setfen=8/kp6/p2R4/2p2pp1/2P4p/8/P7/K7 w - - 0 1]%
      }%
    \end{chessboards}


The number at the top left of each board is generated automatically and need not/cannot be specified.
The font for the number, fontsize for the circled numbers, marginal separations etc. can be configured using key-value syntax.

\chessboardsset{<key-value list>} can be used to configure the various options.

    \chessboardsset{%
      black margin = {25pt},
      column sep = {\columnsep},
      ding size = {\Large},
      no indent = {0.5em + 15pt},
      no font  = {\bfseries\Large},
      no sep = {5pt},
      row sep = {\baselineskip},
      white margin  = {50pt},
    }

would simply (re)set the defaults, for example.
Complete code:
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728002/
\usepackage[margin=1.3in,verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{pifont}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_calculatormathematical_tmpa_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_calculatormathematical_tmpb_coffin
\int_new:N \g_calculatormathematical_boards_int
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__calculatormathematical_whitecircle:n #1
{
  \int_case:nn { #1 }
  {
    { 0 } { }
    { 1 } { \ding{172} }
    { 2 } { \ding{173} }
    { 3 } { \ding{174} }
    { 4 } { \ding{175} }
    { 5 } { \ding{176} }
    { 6 } { \ding{177} }
    { 7 } { \ding{178} }
    { 8 } { \ding{179} }
    { 9 } { \ding{180} }
    { 10 } { \ding{181} }
  }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__calculatormathematical_blackcircle:n #1
{
  \int_case:nn { #1 }
  {
    { 0 } { }
    { 1 } { \ding{182} }
    { 2 } { \ding{183} }
    { 3 } { \ding{184} }
    { 4 } { \ding{185} }
    { 5 } { \ding{186} }
    { 6 } { \ding{187} }
    { 7 } { \ding{188} }
    { 8 } { \ding{189} }
    { 9 } { \ding{190} }
    { 10 } { \ding{191} }
  }
}

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__calculatormathematical_chessboard:nnn #1#2#3
{
  \int_gincr:N \g_calculatormathematical_boards_int
  \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin
  {
    #3
  }
  \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_calculatormathematical_tmpa_coffin
  {
    \l_calculatormathematical_nofont_tl \int_to_arabic:n { \g_calculatormathematical_boards_int }
  }
  \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin { t } { l }
  \l_calculatormathematical_tmpa_coffin { H } { l } { \l_calculatormathematical_noindent_dim } { \l_calculatormathematical_nosep_dim }
  \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_calculatormathematical_tmpb_coffin
  {
    \l_calculatormathematical_dingsize_tl \__calculatormathematical_blackcircle:n {#2}
  }
  \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin { \l_calculatormathematical_tmpa_coffin - vc } { r }
  \l_calculatormathematical_tmpb_coffin { vc } { hc } { -\l_calculatormathematical_blackmarg_dim } { 0pt }
  \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_calculatormathematical_tmpa_coffin
  {
    \l_calculatormathematical_dingsize_tl \__calculatormathematical_whitecircle:n {#1}
  }
  \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin { \l_calculatormathematical_tmpa_coffin - vc } { \l_calculatormathematical_tmpb_coffin - hc }
  \l_calculatormathematical_tmpa_coffin { vc } { hc } { -\l_calculatormathematical_whitemarg_dim } { 0pt }
}
\keys_define:nn { calculatormathematical }
{
  black ~ margin .dim_set:N = \l_calculatormathematical_blackmarg_dim,
  black ~ margin .initial:n = { 25pt },
  column ~ sep .dim_set:N = \l_calculatormathematical_colsep_dim,
  column ~ sep .initial:V = \columnsep,
  ding ~ size .tl_set:N = \l_calculatormathematical_dingsize_tl,
  ding ~ size .initial:n = { \Large } ,
  no ~ indent .dim_set:N = \l_calculatormathematical_noindent_dim,
  no ~ indent .initial:n = {0.5em + 15pt},
  no ~ font .tl_set:N = \l_calculatormathematical_nofont_tl,
  no ~ font .initial:n  = { \bfseries\Large },
  no ~ sep .dim_set:N = \l_calculatormathematical_nosep_dim,
  no ~ sep .initial:n = {5pt},
  row ~ sep .dim_set:N = \l_calculatormathematical_rowsep_dim,
  row ~ sep .initial:V = \baselineskip,
  white ~ margin .dim_set:N = \l_calculatormathematical_whitemarg_dim,
  white ~ margin .initial:n = { 50pt },
}
\bool_new:N \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_bool
\NewDocumentCommand \typesetboard { O {0} D <> {0}   +m }
{
  \bool_if:NF \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_bool
  {
    \group_begin:
  }
  \__calculatormathematical_chessboard:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  \bool_if:NTF \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_bool
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_int
    \int_case:nnF { \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_int }
    {
      { 1 } { \coffin_set_eq:NN \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_coffin \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin }
      { 2 } { \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_coffin { b } { l} \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin { t } { l } { 0pt } { -\l_calculatormathematical_rowsep_dim } }
      { 3 } { \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_coffin { b } { l} \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin { t } { l } { 0pt } { -\l_calculatormathematical_rowsep_dim } }
      { 4 } { \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_coffin { t } { r} \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin { t } { l } { \l_calculatormathematical_colsep_dim } { 0pt } }
      { 5 } { \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_coffin { \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin - b } { r} \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin { t } { r } { 0pt } { -\l_calculatormathematical_rowsep_dim } }
      { 6 } { \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_coffin { b } { r} \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin { b } { r } { 0pt } { 0pt } }
    } {
      \typeout{Oops! ~ Too ~ many !}
    }
  } {
    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_coffin { H } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
    \group_end:
  }
}
\int_new:N \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_int
\NewDocumentEnvironment {chessboards} {}
{
  \int_zero:N \l_calculatormathematical_chessboard_int
  \bool_set_true:N \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_bool
}{
  \begin{center}
    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_calculatormathematical_chessboards_coffin { H } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
  \end{center}
}
\NewDocumentCommand \chessboardsset { m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { calculatormathematical } { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\setchessboard{%
  showmover=false,
  marginleftwidth=.5em,
  marginrightwidth=0pt,
  marginbottomwidth=.5em,
  margintopwidth=0em,
}

\begin{chessboards}
  \typesetboard[1]<1>{%
    \chessboard[setfen=8/3p2k1/2p1p2R/p3P1PK/P2r4/8/8/8 w - - 0 1]%
  }%
  \typesetboard[2]{%
    \chessboard[setfen=8/2r5/3N1p2/3K4/8/1P1k4/8/8 w - - 0 1, inverse]%
  }%
  \typesetboard[5]{%
    \chessboard[setfen=8/7p/8/2p3P1/1p2k3/1P6/2K4P/8 w - - 0 1]%
  }%
  \typesetboard[2]<2>{%
    \chessboard[setfen=8/kp6/p2R4/2p2pp1/2P4p/8/P7/K7 w - - 0 1]%
  }%
  \typesetboard<3>{%
    \chessboard[setfen=8/7p/8/2p3P1/1p2k3/1P6/2K4P/8 w - - 0 1]%
  }%
  \typesetboard[5]{%
    \chessboard[setfen=8/kp6/p2R4/2p2pp1/2P4p/8/P7/K7 w - - 0 1]%
  }%
\end{chessboards}

\typesetboard[1]<1>{%
  \chessboard[ setfen=8/3p2k1/2p1p2R/p3P1PK/P2r4/8/8/8 w - - 0 1]%
}
\end{document}

Edit
To use sans versions of the circled numbers, add 20 to each of the numbers in the \ding{} commands.
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__calculatormathematical_whitecircle:n #1
{
  \int_case:nn { #1 }
  {
    { 0 } { }
    { 1 } { \ding{192} }
    { 2 } { \ding{193} }
    { 3 } { \ding{194} }
    { 4 } { \ding{195} }
    { 5 } { \ding{196} }
    { 6 } { \ding{197} }
    { 7 } { \ding{198} }
    { 8 } { \ding{199} }
    { 9 } { \ding{200} }
    { 10 } { \ding{201} }
  }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__calculatormathematical_blackcircle:n #1
{
  \int_case:nn { #1 }
  {
    { 0 } { }
    { 1 } { \ding{202} }
    { 2 } { \ding{203} }
    { 3 } { \ding{204} }
    { 4 } { \ding{205} }
    { 5 } { \ding{206} }
    { 6 } { \ding{207} }
    { 7 } { \ding{208} }
    { 8 } { \ding{209} }
    { 9 } { \ding{210} }
    { 10 } { \ding{211} }
  }
}


note that Ulrike will probably post some two line method of doing this with chessboard alone, at which point I will delete this. (I really did not check the documentation except to trim the margins ....)

Please dont, it is remarkable work and I thank you very much for it. I will try to adapt a few things like size and maybe the distance between the boards. :P

How can one adjust the horizontal distance between the boards?

@Lonaldin Where it says \columnsep, just write 2\columnsep or 3\columnsep.

@Lonaldin I've added row sep and col sep options and a command, \chessboardsset{}, to configure the column and row spacing. See edit.

@calculatormathematical ^^

Hey, is there an easy way to change the font in the circles (only) to sans serif? I tried it with \sffamily but it does not work...

@calculatormathematical yes, but you have to change the numbers of the \ding{}s to use the sans rather than the serif ranges. the circled numbers are just pre-made symbols from pifont, so the current font doesn't affect the result of \ding{}.

@calculatormathematical see edit for appropriate code chunk.

Is there any setcounter{}{} command for the puzzle number, I run out of compile time...

@calculatormathematical overleaf? I'm really hoping they get the new externalisation packages sooner rather than later ;). \int_gset:Nn \g_calculatormathematical_boards_int {5} after the \int_new:N \g_calculatormathematical_boards_int line will start the counter at 5 (so the first counter would be 6). or it could be added to the key-value interface ...?
